# How to detect whether tying is enabled in the currently selected/active interface in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, focus, keyboard-events, typing

In Windows 7(I am not sure about other OS) when you are on a webpage, pressing the space-bar scrolls a few pixels down the page. But when you are in an interface where typing can be done(like an input element, textarea, word editor, code editor, search bar, etc), pressing the space-bar obviously types a space.

Similarly, when all the open windows or menus are minimized, and you are viewing the desktop, and you press a letter key, instead of the letter being typed somewhere, a beep sound is produced.

This shows that the availability of a typing functionality can be "detected". And if it can be detected, it can most likely be done so using C++.

I don't know what to call this. I tried to find out using google but everything I got seemed unrelated to this. I was probably not using the correct keywords.

Whatever this is, I am creating a C++ program where I need to be able to detect it(in an if condition). Something like this

```
if (/*typing can be done*/) {
//Do something..........
}
```

Or this

```
if (/*typing can NOT be done*/) {
if( GetKeyState(VK_SPACE) & 0x8000 ) {
//Do something..........
}
}
```

And I need to be able to do so natively. Not specific to a particular console window or UI.

If you can help me in any way in figuring this out than please do so. And please feel free to make or suggest relevant edits to improve this question and make it less vague and more detailed and to-the-point.

Comment: Wrong conclusion. If you hear a beep, all it means is that no window procedure was able handle the keyboard input. It does not tell you anything about what a window procedure ultimately makes out of that keyboard input. In conclusion, neither you nor the OS can detect *"typing functionality"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you describe belongs to the program running the window with focus, not to the operating system (although the operating system will, at least in part, ultimately power that functionality). It shouldn't come as a surprise that programs can detect keystrokes, because otherwise you wouldn't be able to use your keyboard to input any characters into your computer.

However, you cannot just "detect" a random event with an `if` statement. **"if" is not "when"**. Your computer will not repeatedly check all `if` statements in your program and jump to that location in the code whenever one matches. Imagine the chaos!

A program sufficiently complex to have a graphical interface almost certainly has an "event loop", be this in its own code or buried within an API call (as in the case of native Windows applications); such an event loop typically polls for keys being sent to the window(s) managed by the program. If you do not have an event loop (and if your operating system cannot generate a "signal" when a keystroke otherwise goes unhandled), you will have to make one.

Exact specifics are beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer, but by pointing you in the direction of a textbook about how to create graphical programs, I am enabling you to discover how input and output is handled in those cases.

Comment: At the moment I don't know whether to mark your answer as correct or not(due to my own incomplete knowledge and more importantly it might discourage other people from posting answers). I can't upvote, eventhough I want to(my reputation is <15), but thank you very much for posting an answer.

Comment: ps do you think that blinking cursor that is always there in typing interfaces(such as the comment box I am typing in right now) can be "detected"

Comment: @javabhai: You'd have to be more specific about your needs. In general, a program that owns some text widgets knows which text widget has the "focus". But can you literally detect the little blinking caret, or _when_ it blinks? Not normally, no. Then again, I can't think of a reason to.

Comment: You're absolutely right not to accept this answer yet - it's way too early for that!